# Phalcon view controller is not controlling the view

Tags: php, view, phalcon, volt

I'm programming an admin web ui for a online system, I managed to mount a url to the view using,

```
$app->get(
        "/main/index",
        function () use ($app){
            //no echo here
            $app["view"]->render(
                "main","index"
            );
        }
   );
```

And my Main controller is like,

```
<?php

class MainController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->tag->setTitle('Home Page');

        $this->view->setTemplateAfter('nav');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
}
```

My view structure is like,

```
views
--layouts
----index.volt
----nav.volt
--main
----index.volt
--index.volt
```

My problem is no matter how I change the MainController code, it doesn't affect anything on the rendered view `main,index`. So I wish to know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `render` is for your view template, the second is for your view parameters.

```
$app->get(
    "/main/index",
      function () use ($app) {
          $app["view"]->render(
              "main/index"
          );
      }
);
```

Just change `"main","index"` to `"main/index"` and your view should render.